# What is the bundle identifier of apple's default applications in iOS?

Tags: ios, bundle, identifier

I need to know the bundle identifiers for apple applications, such as mail, contacts, safari, photos, game center, settings, calendar, iPod, App store, camera, ... After searching for quite a while I found out they may be com.apple.{somethingelse}

Comment: Why do you need to know them? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to get a copy of their purplenamedport using the private framework GraphicsServices GSEvent.h function
mach_port_t GSCopyPurpleNamedPort(cstring appBundleIdentifier); I know it sounds fairly complicated, but all I need is the bundle identifier.

Comment: Is this for an app going in the App Store?

Comment: It is not, it is aimed for a private monitoring service, and I want to test it with this applications.

Comment: apple mail is com.apple.mobilemail

Comment: Here are some official lists, directly from Apple: iOS/iPadOS: https://support.apple.com/guide/mdm/ios-bundle-ids-mdm90f60c1ce/web tvOS: https://support.apple.com/guide/mdm/tvos-bundle-ids-mdmc90dce69e/web

Answer (score 36, accepted):

These are from iPhone 4S iOS 5.0.1

```
Camera:       com.apple.camera
AppStore:     com.apple.AppStore
Contacts:     com.apple.MobileAddressBook
Mail:         com.apple.mobilemail
GameCenter:   com.apple.gamecenter
MobileSafari: com.apple.mobilesafari
Preferences:  com.apple.Preferences
iPod:         com.apple.mobileipod
Photos:       com.apple.mobileslideshow
Calendar:     com.apple.mobilecal
Clock:        com.apple.mobiletimer
```

Comment: Clock is `com.apple.mobiletimer` in iOS 9.3, not the value listed above

Answer (score 26):

This is the verified list as of iOS 9.3:

```
App Store - com.apple.AppStore
Calculator - com.apple.calculator
Calendar - com.apple.mobilecal
Camera - com.apple.camera
Clock - com.apple.mobiletimer
Compass - com.apple.compass
Contacts - com.apple.MobileAddressBook
FaceTime - com.apple.facetime
Find Friends - com.apple.mobileme.fmf1
Find iPhone - com.apple.mobileme.fmip1
Game Center - com.apple.gamecenter
Health - com.apple.Health
iBooks - com.apple.iBooks
iTunes Store - com.apple.MobileStore
Mail - com.apple.mobilemail
Maps - com.apple.Maps
Messages - com.apple.MobileSMS
Music - com.apple.Music
News - com.apple.news
Notes - com.apple.mobilenotes
Phone - com.apple.mobilephone
Photos - com.apple.mobileslideshow
Podcasts - com.apple.podcasts
Reminders - com.apple.reminders
Safari - com.apple.mobilesafari
Settings - com.apple.Preferences
Stocks - com.apple.stocks
Tips - com.apple.tips
Videos - com.apple.videos
Voice Memos - com.apple.VoiceMemos
Wallet - com.apple.Passbook
Watch - com.apple.Bridge
Weather - com.apple.weather
```

The complete, up-to-date list is available here:

http://labs.wrprojects.com/apple-ios-9-3-native-app-bundle-identifiers/

Answer (score 10):

Here is what I was able to find on the subject, although I won't claim that all of these will be 100% accurate considering how many different sources I pulled these from (and some of them didn't seem very credible) but either way this is what I found... Good luck!

```
com.apple.springboard
com.apple.mobilephone
com.apple.MobileSMS
com.apple.mobilesafari
com.apple.MobileStore
com.apple.stocks
com.apple.weather
com.apple.MobileAddressBook
com.apple.mobileipod-MediaPlayer
com.apple.gamecenter
com.apple.VoiceMemos
com.apple.compass
com.apple.calendar(com.apple.caldav or com.apple.ical)
com.apple.mail(or com.apple.mobilemail not completely sure)
```

Answer (score 5):

some more tested on iOS7

```
Apple Maps:  com.apple.Maps
Notes:       com.apple.mobilenotes
Reminders:   com.apple.reminders
Videos:      com.apple.videos
Passbook:    com.apple.Passbook
Calculator:  com.apple.calculator
Music:       com.apple.Music
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the verified list as of iOS 9.3:

`App Store - com.apple.AppStore
Calculator - com.apple.calculator
Calendar - com.apple.mobilecal
Camera - com.apple.camera
Clock - com.apple.mobiletimer
Compass - com.apple.compass
Contacts - com.apple.MobileAddressBook
FaceTime - com.apple.facetime
Find Friends - com.apple.mobileme.fmf1
Find iPhone - com.apple.mobileme.fmip1
Game Center - com.apple.gamecenter
Health - com.apple.Health
iBooks - com.apple.iBooks
iTunes Store - com.apple.MobileStore
Mail - com.apple.mobilemail
Maps - com.apple.Maps
Messages - com.apple.MobileSMS
Music - com.apple.Music
News - com.apple.news
Notes - com.apple.mobilenotes
Phone - com.apple.mobilephone
Photos - com.apple.mobileslideshow
Podcasts - com.apple.podcasts
Reminders - com.apple.reminders
Safari - com.apple.mobilesafari
Settings - com.apple.Preferences
Stocks - com.apple.stocks
Tips - com.apple.tips
Videos - com.apple.videos
Voice Memos - com.apple.VoiceMemos
Wallet - com.apple.Passbook
Watch - com.apple.Bridge
Weather - com.apple.weather`

The complete, up-to-date list is available here: http://labs.wrprojects.com/apple-ios-9-3-native-app-bundle-identifiers/

Answer (score 1):

There are search engines for Bundle IDs that look up current Bundle IDs, for example this one:
http://offcornerdev.com/bundleid.html
Just type the name of the app into the search field and it gives you the Bundle ID. Works for all apps in the AppStore and of course Apple stock apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a bundle identifier of a process on the simulator you can use `xcrun simctl spawn booted launchctl print system` which will print the complete list of active bundle identifiers. It's a bit broad but it can be very useful to make an educated guess.