# How to check if app launched from TestFlight or App Store?

Tags: ios, launching-application

I want to check if my app was opened from the `TestFlight` app or the `AppStore` app.

I made a test and found this information in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` when launching it from `TestFlight`:

```
if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String == "com.apple.TestFlight" {
    // ...
}
```

But I don't know how to check if the app is opened from the `AppStore`. What's the identifier?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910366/what-is-the-bundle-identifier-of-apples-default-applications-in-ios So maybe `com.apple.AppStore`?

Comment: is there a reason you couldn't just use
else {
     // App Store
}

Comment: @Larme That's what I thought but I wasn't sure and couldn't find any information about it... Thank you!

Comment: @ZacharyBell Yeah that's because my app may actually be opened by different means (App Store, Test Flight, classic tap, deeplinking...) so I want to check each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bundle Identifier for the App Store iOS app is `com.apple.AppStore`