# what's value of UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey when app launch from app store

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to track the app launch source.
I check UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: to know how the app be launched
but i don't know the value of UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey when app is launched from app store.
Does anyone know？

how i track launch source:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if let launchOptions = launchOptions {
            if let url = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.url] {
                //wake from other app
                //the problem is i don't know the value of "url"
             }
        } else {
            //wake from desktop
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to look at the sourceApplication key:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/launchoptionskey/1623064-sourceapplication

From experimentation with my own app that launches (through a custom protocol) another app of mine, I see that the `sourceApplication` value contains the `bundle identifier` of the source app.

So, for your case, I expect that it would be:

```
com.apple.AppStore
```

See: [What is the bundle identifier of apple's default applications in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910366/what-is-the-bundle-identifier-of-apples-default-applications-in-ios)

But I don't know this for sure.

Commentary: It's probably not good to rely on this sort of stuff because the OS could change to invalidate this assumption. But I don't really know your use case.